# Show/Hide object orientations in Blender 2.8?

Tags: axis

I can't find the option to show/hide the local axis/orientation in the Blender 2.8 UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and setting the Object DATA Properties (green stick figure icon, 2nd from bottom) helped.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In short: armature properties/viewport display/axes

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, and you're right. This displays the root axes for the whole armature.  What I'm really looking for is how to display all joints local axes, I couldn't find an image with what I'm looking for.  I'm working on mocap retargeting, so I can visually see which is the pitch,roll,yaw axis, without having to go to the rotate tool for each joint to check..  I should've asked a more specific question to begin with.  I'll create another question, now that I have a better idea of what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @SeanNovak this is working at bones level too. What do you mean? You can edit your question if don't want to add another one.